# Braces in l3keys

Tags: expl3, best-practices, key-value, l3keys

In many cases, the braces surrounding values to keys in `l3keys` are omitted when defining keys, even when the keys themselves have `n`-,`c`-, or `e`-type arguments, which normally require braced arguments. Isn't this inconsistent and more confusing than providing the braces?

My questions: (1) Why are the braces sometimes omitted? (2) Which is best-practice for programming in `expl3`?

My MWE is a just a quick demonstration of defining keys using `l3keys` without using braced values. In the commented-out code, the keys are defined with braced values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { my }
  {
    string .str_set:c = l__my_tmpa_str , % note the 'c'-type argument
    string .initial:n = initial ,
    string .value_required:n = true ,
    stringadd .code:n = \str_put_right:Nn \l__my_tmpa_str { foo } ,
    stringadd .value_forbidden:n = true ,
    stringadde .code:n = \str_put_right:Ne \l__my_tmpa_str {#1} ,
    stringadde .value_required:n = true
  }
% \keys_define:nn { my }
%   {
%     string .str_set:c = { l__my_tmpa_str } ,
%     string .initial:n = { initial } ,
%     string .value_required:n = { true } ,
%     stringadd .code:n = { \str_put_right:Nn \l__my_tmpa_str { foo } } ,
%     stringadd .value_forbidden:n = { true } , 
%     stringadde .code:n = { \str_put_right:Ne \l__my_tmpa_str {#1} } ,
%     stringadde .value_required:n = { true }
%   }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_use:N \l__my_tmpa_str
\par
\keys_set:nn { my }
  {
    string = blah
  }
\str_use:N \l__my_tmpa_str
\par
\keys_set:nn { my }
  {
    stringadd
  }
\str_use:N \l__my_tmpa_str
\par
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { blah!!! }
\keys_set:nn { my }
  {
    stringadde = \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\str_use:N \l__my_tmpa_str
\par
\keys_set:nn { my } { stringadd }
\str_use:N \l__my_tmpa_str
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say best practice would be following `interface3.pdf` which does use braces for arguments of these types with the exception of boolean values (`true`|`false`) which are standardly non-standard ;). E.g. `⟨key ⟩ .initial:n = {⟨value ⟩}` (page 241). Note that 'required' is a bit optimistic here. `expl3` syntax is typically unenforced, so the fact that it works doesn't make the case of setting or defining keys any different from other cases. Any differences emerge from the underlying TeX as collateral damage.

Comment: In a lot of the example code in `l3keys`, the braces are omitted.

Comment: you want to be able to omit braces around the value at the top level key use `fontsize=12pt` not `\fontsize={12pt}` so pretty much all kv systems take the value as everything from `=` to the next `,` or end, possibly with space stripping, as the value, Then allow stipping of one level of braces to hide any `=` or `,` that need hiding. l3keys uses kv syntax also for defining the keys so you see the same here. If your initial value was `a,b` not `initial` then the braces would be needed. As it isn't, they are optional.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is one strange package that does no brace stripping at all by design... And there are some which strip more than one set of braces sometimes. Pretty buggy :P

Comment: @Skillmon details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a documentation in `interface3` that defines what is valid input inside `key=value`-lists (see subsection 27.10). I don't want to repeat everything here, but it boils down to the following:

Braces are optional and don't make a difference unless (outside any nested braces):

- your value includes commas
- your value includes at least one equals sign
- your value has at least one space on either end

If none of the above are true, the braces are completely optional (and indeed you get better performance if they are omitted, because TeX has to shift fewer tokens around).

So, what is "best practice": Whatever you find easier to be read and maintained -- and if you're after minute speed improvements omitting every unnecessary set of braces. But as soon as you forward user input you don't know whether that will include spaces/commas/equals signs, so in that case you should absolutely use braces.